# Finding a Taylor series for an integral

Tags: calculus

I have a question,

I'm supposed to find a Taylor series (center = $0$) for this integral:

$$\displaystyle \int_{0}^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t^4}$$

But the definite integral portion is confusing me a bit. Should the integral be evaluated at $0$ to $x$ after the series is found? Should the bounds be ignored? My textbook doesn't cover this situation!

Thanks!

Comment: Do what you always did to compute Taylor series, except now, remember that when you take derivatives, you have your friend the Fundamental Theorem to help you out.

Comment: The series for $\frac{1}{1+t^4}$ is $1-t^4+t^8-t^{12}+\cdots$. Integrate term by term from $0$ to $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Denote $f(x)$ the given integral. Then 
$$f'(x)=\frac1{1+x^4}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n x^{4n},\;\forall \vert x\vert<1\;,$$
and so by integrating term by term we get

$$f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)dt=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{4n+1} x^{4n+1}$$